# Find out execution environment for php script

Tags: php

Is there a way to find out if a php script is executed in a terminal that supports color control characters?

I would like to be able to execute the same script from my mac terminal or from the sublime text console without passing a flag for color support, and I would like the color control characters to be printed when run in the terminal window, but now when run from the sublime text console.

I assume this is possible, since programs like googletest have colorful output when run directly from the terminal, but don't print color control characters when executed from inside a php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need `variables_order` in php.ini to contain `E` so that `$_ENV` is populated.

   ```
   # php -i | grep variables_order
   variables_order => EGPCS => EGPCS
   ```
2. Check `$_ENV['TERM']`
3. See if it's in [this list](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals#Terminal_256_color_support_list).